# C++ How to get process ID from filename of DLL(windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process

how can I get a process ID from a filename?
Like: `int processId = getProcessIdByFileName("Network.dll");`
Btw, which datatype has the process ID?

Extended info:
I have the source code of a DLL. This DLL gets loaded to an application, like a few other DLL's. I want to hook the other DLL's functions. Therefore I need the process ID of them(is there a process ID for each DLL if they all run under one application?

How could I call functions of the other DLL's inside of my DLL? How to get a handle to them?

Comment: "they all run under one application" ? One application is one process. Therefore, one process id for the whole app, it's not per loaded lib or something. Unless it's application, that uses IPC?

Comment: There could be many process IDs. There will be one for each process that loads the DLL. Do you perhaps mean module handle rather than process ID?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want the process ID, nothing you can do with that.  Maybe the module handle, use GetModuleHandle().  But you probably really want Microsoft Detours, assuming "hooking" is accurate.

Comment: Is it possible for COM to load a DLL for an application as a separate process? Or are components designed to do that packaged as EXE files?

Comment: @Steve314, yes, COM can load a DLL in an out-of-process surrogate server process. But this out-of-process server can, in principle, host multiple DLLs.

Comment: Why don't you simply replace this "other DLL" with a DLL of your own that exports the same functions?

Answer (score 3):

DLLs do not have process IDs. A DLL may be loaded into multiple processes, or none at all. A DLL may be loaded into a process, later unloaded, and then loaded again. It is meaningless to talk of the process ID of a DLL. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I try to hook a DLL from my own DLL, where both are loaded to one application. I want to apply the hook for all DLL's loaded to the app and the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, and here's why. DLLs are shared between processes. It may only have one "owning" process, it may have many. You CAN determine which dlls a program has loaded (e.g. dependency walker) however you can't determine which programs (if any) are attached to a DLL.

Comment: But, how can I hook one DLL from my own DLL, where both are loaded to one application. I want to apply the hook for all DLL's loaded to the app and the app itself.

Comment: I have the source code of a DLL. This DLL gets loaded to an application, like a few other DLL's. I want to hook the other DLL's functions. I want to apply the hook - every DLL and the application should call the hooked function instead of the original!!!! :)

Comment: @lolo - applying hooks that affect other applications using the same DLL (or doing anything to directly tamper with another process) is frowned upon. IIRC, it used to be easy enough in the 16-bit Windows days, but changes were made in Win32 to make it harder. It *is* still possible, though, probably by using the same APIs that debuggers use. Beware, though - if you break other applications on your users machines, people won't stop at frowning.

Answer (score 0):

Process ID in Windows is not staticaly embedded inside file, its a property that any DLL, EXE or executable has once its running. Check Toolhelp API,  you`ll find all answers there.

To call functions from other DLL you need to load that DLL dynamicaly, check here for an example  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/dynamicdllloading.aspx

Comment: I wanted to load the DLL by looking up the file name for a process name and by looking up the process name for an ID.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs are not run, they are loaded by processes so this is not possible. You can however look for the PID of a process by using its path or name ie. Get PID of "explorer.exe"

You could get the PID's of the processes that have loaded the specific DLL. ie.

```
int PIDs[128];
GetDependentProcesses(PIDs, "Kernel32.dll"); //Custom function, not built in

for(int x = 0; x < 128; x++)
{
   cout << PIDs[x] << " Depends on Kernel32.dll\n";
}
```

And you cant hook a DLL, only a process.